# Copy files out of nested subdirectories into another folder

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a parent directory (call it Parent) which includes nested subdirectories. I want to copy jpeg files in nested subdirectories to another directory (call it NEW). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new python script with the following code:

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

src_dir = "your/source/dir"
dst_dir = "your/destination/dir"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

the save it "filename.py"
and in terminal run "python filename.py"

Comment: I checked that but my destination directory is empty yet.what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** + **`cp`** solution:

```
find Parent -type f -name"*.jpeg" -exec cp -t NEW {} +
```

Comment: Destination folder is empty and I get the error cp: illegal option -- t

Comment: @Hossein, check your `cp` implementation and check if you copy/pasted correctly. There's nothing erroneous in the above simple approach

Comment: The problem is with the -t flag. 

cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory

Comment: On macos, there is no `-t`

Comment: @cricket_007, if macos - then tags for the question have been chosen improperly

Comment: I can't control other's beliefs that `bash` and the binaries provided by the OS all are considered to be the same "linux" utilities